Elementary embedding between transitive classes and well-foundedness of ultrapower of V
I wish to understand some statements given in the wikipedia article on critical points in set theory, comparing them with the stated source (Jech's Set theory). Specifically:
Let $j: N \to M$ be an elementary embedding where $N,M$ are transitive classes. Assume that $N = V$, the universe of sets. Further assume $M$ to be an ultrapower of $V$ with respect to some ultra filter $U$ on some set $S$.
Here are my questions:

Just to make sure I get this: $j(\omega) = \omega$ because $j(n) = n ~ \forall n < \omega$ and $j$ respects the union operation, right? In the stated source the proof of this statement uses that $U$ is countably complete (Jech, p.286 at the bottom; $U$ is $\sigma$-complete by assumption here): Whenever $[f] < \omega$, $f(x) = n$ almost everywhere. Why does Jech take this approach, or am I missing something? (Also, doesn't his approach only show that $j(\omega) \geq \omega$, which we already know?)

In Jech's book it further says that in our case, $M$ is well-founded whenever $U$ forms a $\sigma$-complete ultrafilter on $S$. The non-existence of an infinite descending chain is clear to me. As we are working with a proper class $V$, we want to make sure that for any given function $f$ with domain $V$ the family of all equivalence classes $[g]$ for $g \in^* f$ is itself a set. Here, the underlying equivalence relation is given by "almost equality with respect to $U$" ($ =^* $) and the definition of the respective equivalence classes $[g]$ makes sure that $[g]$ itself forms a set. My question is: How exactly do we use that $U$ is an ultrafilter to bound the number of possible $g \in^* f$? ($g \in^* f$ if and only if $\{ x \in S : g(x) \in f(x) \} \in U$).


Thank you for your help!

The union is absolutely not preserved by an elementary embedding. Otherwise there would be no critical point. In the context of what you write, you can argue that $j(\omega)=\omega$ because $M$ is transitive, so it is correct about $\omega$.

To your first question, as explained by Jonathan in the comments, no that's not the correct reasoning. If it were, then there couldn't be any critical point. Sure, $\omega$ is the union of all ordinals $\alpha<\omega$ (or just $\bigcup \omega$)... what elementarity says is that $j(\omega)$ is the union of all ordinals $\alpha < j(\omega)$ or that $j(\omega) = \cup j(\omega)$, which is not very exciting (just means it's a limit ordinal).
However, as also mentioned, there is a simpler argument: $\omega$ is definable and absolute for transitive models, so we will have $j(\omega) = \omega^M=\omega$. But, for larger amounts of completeness, the argument given in Jech can be used to show $j(\gamma) = \gamma$ in more general cases when $\gamma \ne \omega.$ (i.e.  showing $j(\gamma) = \gamma$ for $\gamma< \kappa$ when the ultrafilter is $\kappa$-complete).
To the second question, we aren't trying to bound the number of possible $g\in^*f,$ we are trying to bound the number of possible $[g]\in^*[f]$. But for any representative $f,$ if $[g]\in [f]$ this means $g(\alpha)<f(\alpha)$ almost always, so by replacing some values on a measure zero set, we see $[g]$ has a representative in $\prod_{\alpha}\min(f(\alpha),1)$, and so there are only set-many possible $[g]$'s.
